# How to change the style and color of edittext content on button click at run time

Tags: android

I am developing a cloth design android application. In which i want to change the style of text of edit text  on required button click and same thing for text color.

My xml file is.......

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mvieww"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/etext"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

please help me........

Comment: you can use `editText.setTextColor()` for changing text color

Comment: value used in setTextcolor()?

Comment: its int value of color you want to use.. if you have color code then you can use `Color.parseColor("#FF66FF")` to get int value from color code

Comment: `editText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f71265"));` change color code '#f71265' with your required color code

Answer (score 1):

To set the color, use :

```
 textView.setTextColor(Color.SOMECOLOR);
```

To set the font, use :

```
textView.setTypeFace(SOMEFONT);
```

If you don't actually know how to set it to the click of a button, then here's how you do it:

First, make a `Button`. I'll just assume you named it `button`.
Set it via `findViewById(R.whateverTheIdOfTheButtonIs)`

Then, you will need to do :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Set the text color or font here
            }
        });
```

Comment: what value of  somecolor in (Color.SOMECOLOR) will be used and from where will be access?

Comment: What do you mean? The Color class has a whole bunch of ints that you can use which'll define the color.

Such as Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, and so on so forth. 

See : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

Comment: Actually i m using a edit text and i wanna that as i write something in edit text after writing i wanna change the color after button click

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can set the style programatically. To get around this you can create a template layout xml file with the style assigned, for example in res/layout create tvtemplate.xml as with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a template"
        style="@style/my_style" />


EditText myText = (EditText)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tvtemplate, null);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will update the style as well as color of your `EditText` text when you click `yourButton`

```
 yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              yourEditText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=red><b>"+yourEditText.getText().toString()+"</b></font>"));// set style and color  

            }
        });
```